# How do I run the GraalVM native image tracing agent from a Spring Native Gradle project?

Tags: gradle, graalvm, spring-native

I have found information on how to run the GraalVM native image tracing agent from a Spring Native Maven project, but I can't find info on how to do it from a Gradle project.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_it_with_maven.

Any ideas on how to do it from a Gradle project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assisted configuration javaagent is orthogonal to the build tool, so one needs to specify the correct arguments to the jvm running the tests:

Something like this which the docs you reference outline: `-agentlib:native-image-agent=access-filter-file=access-filter.json,config-output-dir=target/classes/META-INF/native-image`

I think in Gradle you just configure the `test` task with it:

```
test { 
  jvmArgs -agentlib:native-image-agent=access-filter-file=access-filter.json,config-output-dir=target/classes/META-INF/native-image
}
```

Here's Gradle docs on the test task: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried with:

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs '-agentlib:native-image-agent=access-filter-file=src/test/resources/access-filter.json,config-output-dir=ml'
}

I hoped to get some output in the folder "ml", but it was empty after running:  

    ./gradlew clean bootBuildImage

Comment: I think it adds the jvmArgs for the test runs. Is it still empty after `./gradlew test`?

Comment: Yes it does! Given that GraalVM is installed and added to $PATH :-)
Running ./gradlew test works for me, I guess. I can  thenmove the files after inspection to src/resources/META-INF/native-image and run a separate ./gradlew bootBuildImage command. I'll try it out!

Comment: Just to confirm this works perfectly fine. My native compiled Spring Boot apps runs perfectly fina now. Amazing to see them start up in 150 ms :-)